# Linux Azure VM web server not accesible

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have created a resource management VM, installed nginx and can't seem to access it from outside, did an ip forward from the options, also set up a static DNS, can't seem to find a solution.

Inbound / Outbound http 80 allowed.

Tested localhost with wget and works.

[Wget localhost / IP Forward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlaEz.jpg)

[Inbound / Outbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I76tb.jpg)

Comment: This is pretty much "My VM doesn't work - how do I fix it?" without any concrete information posted. You didn't show how you set up port forwarding "from the options." You didn't show your inbound/outbound settings. You didn't talk about whether you can reach your site via localhost when ssh'd. Aside from all that: This belongs on ServerFault (when you update it; in its current state, it'll be closed there too).

Answer (score 0):

I rebuilt the VM as Classic and NOT as Resource Manage, did the trick with the configuration from the setup.